# JavaScript returns undefined for parent and children element

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to select the parent element of a clicked button, and find the  child elements text of that parent element however it is returning `undefined`.

```
  var add = document.getElementById("add").parentElement.nodeName;
```

I found how we can access the parent element's node name, but I can't select it's child element by `id`.

Currently I am trying to get attributes for selected elements and user `alert()` to display them, however it's not working as expected. The code below is what I currently have:

```js
window.onload = function(){ 
    add();
}
function add() {
  var add = document.querySelector(".add").parentNode;
  var id = document.querySelector(".id").innerHTML;
  var name = document.querySelector(".std").innerHTML;
  alert(id);
  alert(name);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <table>
   <tr>
     <th>S.N.</th><th>Name</th><th>Action</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td class='id'>1</td><td class='std'>Riya</td><td id='del'>DEL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class='id'>2</td><td class='std'>Sonam</td><td class='add'>ADD</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you shouldn't use multiple elements with the same id

Comment: Your html is invalid. the id should be unique, and yours aren't. You have two divs with `ìd="sn"` and two td with `id="name"`.

Comment: I have changed id and make unique, still undefined.

Comment: What exactly is "returning undefined" here? *"but how to select it's child element by id"* You just use `document.getElementById`. IDs are unique withing a document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. you should use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) when selecting a single element, rather than [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which is used to select multiple elements
2. the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) field should be used instead of `innerHtml`

Note that `document.querySelector()` returns the first selected element (if any), where as `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) containing selected elements.

Here's a working snippet:

```js
window.onload = function(){ 
    add();
}
function add() {
  var add = document.getElementById("add").parentNode;

  /* Use querySelector for single element, and use innerHTML */
  var id = document.querySelector("#id").innerHTML;
  var name = document.querySelector("#std").innerHTML;

  alert(id);
  alert(name);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <table>
   <tr>
     <th>S.N.</th><th>Name</th><th>Action</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td id='sn'>1</td><td id='name'>Riya</td><td id='del'>DEL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td id='id'>2</td><td id='std'>Sonam</td><td id='add'>ADD</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I was just about to write this (I was testing in a codepen to make sure), and it said  "1 New Answer to this question"

Comment: @Dacre Denny Thanks. One question, Though I had not asked previously. Let assume, I have to select only `chld` elements of `tr` which contains `element` add,. Usage of `ID` in my previous snippet messed what I am searching. Now I have changed unique `id` to same class, how can I get specific `class` with parent node relation

Comment: @Hemant you're welcome :-) . For class selection, replace `#` with `.` in your selector. So `document.querySelector(".add")` to select the first element with `class="add"`

Answer (score 0):

`id` attribute value must be unique across your HTML. So if you want to have multiple elements with the same identifier use `class`, also you need to know the index of the element you are targeting.

visit [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/hTml/html_id.asp) for more info about id attribute

You have a typo, the correct attribute is `innerHTML` not innerHtml and as mentioned before you need to know the index of the element

```js
window.onload = function(){ 
    add();
}
function add() {
  var add = document.getElementById("add").parentNode;
  var id = document.querySelectorAll("#id")[0].innerHTML;
  var name = document.querySelectorAll("#std")[0].innerHTML;
  alert(id);
  alert(name);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <table>
   <tr>
     <th>S.N.</th><th>Name</th><th>Action</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td id='sn'>1</td><td id='name'>Riya</td><td id='del'>DEL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td id='id'>2</td><td id='std'>Sonam</td><td id='add'>ADD</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have edited question. now id are unique, result is still undefined